# php - Replace emoticons in string with images

Tags: php, str-replace, emoticons

1. multiple shortcut keys
2. without new lines
3. without loops

   ```
   function smilies($string)
       {
           $emote = array(':)', ':(', ':P', ':D' , '^_^', ';)', ':3', ':*', '<3' );


           $emote_replace = array(
               '<img title=":)" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: 0px;" >',
               '<img title=":(" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -16px;" >',
               '<img title=":P" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -31px;" >',
               '<img title=":D" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -46px;" >',
               '<img title="^_^" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -239px;" >',
               '<img title=";)" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -79px;" >',
               '<img title=":3" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -319px;" >',
               '<img title=":*" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -208px;" >',
               '<img title="<3" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -224px;" >',
           );


               return str_replace($emote, $emote_replace, $string);
           }
   ```

I want to replace **:p**, **:P** without adding new lines to $emote_replace and for **;(** and **:'(** (this is the fb shortcut for cry)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the case with regular expressions (creating the first array could be simpler with a loop) :

```
function smilies($string) {
    $emote = array(
        '/'.preg_quote(':)').'/i',
        '/'.preg_quote(':(').'/i',
        '/'.preg_quote(':P').'/i',
        '/'.preg_quote(':D').'/i',
        '/'.preg_quote('^_^').'/i',
        '/'.preg_quote(';)').'/i',
        '/'.preg_quote(':3').'/i',
        '/'.preg_quote(':*').'/i',
        '/'.preg_quote('<3').'/i'
    );

    $emote_replace = array(
        '<img title=":)" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: 0px;" >',
        '<img title=":(" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -16px;" >',
        '<img title=":P" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -31px;" >',
        '<img title=":D" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -46px;" >',
        '<img title="^_^" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -239px;" >',
        '<img title=";)" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -79px;" >',
        '<img title=":3" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -319px;" >',
        '<img title=":*" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -208px;" >',
        '<img title="<3" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -224px;" >',
    );

    return preg_replace($emote, $emote_replace, $string);
}
```

Comment: This will fix :p and :P but what about different version of the emoticons like :O :-O without adding new line to $emote_replace, because is duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Just change `str_replace` with [`str_ireplace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php). This is the case-insensitive version of `str_replace`.

Comment: This will fix :p and :P but what about different version of the emoticons like :O :-O without adding new line to $emote_replace, because is duplicate

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this without adding something new to your code sincerely...

Answer (score 0):

I modified the function of sebcap26

```
<?php
function smilies($string) {
  $emote = array(
    '/([:][-]?[)])/i', //:) or :-)
    '/([:][-]?[(])/i', //:( or :-(
    '/([:][-]?[P])/i', //:p or :P or :-p or :-P
    '/([:][-]?[D])/i', //:d or :D or :-d or :-D
    '/([^][-]?[^])/i', //^^ or ^-^
    '/([;][-]?[)])/i', //;) or ;-)
    '/'.preg_quote(':3').'/i',
    '/'.preg_quote(':*').'/i',
    '/'.preg_quote('<3').'/i'
  );

  $emote_replace = array(
    '<img title=":)" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: 0px;" >',
    '<img title=":(" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -16px;" >',
    '<img title=":P" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -31px;" >',
    '<img title=":D" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -46px;" >',
    '<img title="^_^" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -239px;" >',
    '<img title=";)" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -79px;" >',
    '<img title=":3" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -319px;" >',
    '<img title=":*" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -208px;" >',
    '<img title="<3" class="emote_img" src="/public/img/blank.gif" style="background-position: -224px;" >',
  );

  return preg_replace($emote, $emote_replace, $string);
}
?>
```

I changed the regex of the first to cover the cases in which it may appear the '-' (hiphen), put it as optional.